# How to remove decimals from a float result?

Tags: android, floating-point, integer

in my app i calculate the CPU usage and i get the result in % but sometimes the result is too big 20.234234234234 
My question is, how can i completely remove the result numbers after the "."?
 And can i do this without changing float to integer?

Here is my code:

```
    private float readCpuUsage() {
    try {
        RandomAccessFile reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/stat", "r");
        String load = reader.readLine();

        String[] toks = load.split(" ");

        long idle1 = Long.parseLong(toks[5]);
        long cpu1 = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3])
                + Long.parseLong(toks[4]) + Long.parseLong(toks[6])
                + Long.parseLong(toks[7]) + Long.parseLong(toks[8]);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(360);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        reader.seek(0);
        load = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();

        toks = load.split(" ");

        long idle2 = Long.parseLong(toks[5]);
        long cpu2 = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3])
                + Long.parseLong(toks[4]) + Long.parseLong(toks[6])
                + Long.parseLong(toks[7]) + Long.parseLong(toks[8]);

        return (float) (cpu2 - cpu1) / ((cpu2 + idle2) - (cpu1 + idle1));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To print the result i just throw:

```
      textview.setText((readCpuUsage() * 100) + "%");
```

where readCpuUsage() is the result and to transform it to % i multiply it with 100
**This is how i did it:**

```
    float xxz=readCpuUsage()*100;
    textview.setText(String.format("%.0f",xxz) + "%");
```

Comment: Please edit your question and write how you're currently printing the float literal. Your function is irrelevant here if the question is just a matter of proper formatting.

Comment: Decimals? Do you mean decimal *places*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try This it may be help to you

```
String.format("%.0f",floatvalue);
```

or

```
Float.parseFloat(String.format("%.0f",floatvalue))
```

Comment: float xxz=readCpuUsage()*100;
textview.setText(String.format("%.0f",xxz) + "%");

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are unnecessarily complicating things.

When you know for sure that you do not want the decimal component of your number you should just use the `integer` or `long` types. Unless you have a valid reason or specific bias against the int datatype.

Answer (score 0):

There is only Long type used in the below operation hence the result will be always long.

> return (float) (cpu2 - cpu1) / ((cpu2 + idle2) - (cpu1 + idle1));

I don't understand why are you typecasting it to float at the first place.

Just change the return type to long from float.
And change the return statement to :

> return (cpu2 - cpu1) / ((cpu2 + idle2) - (cpu1 + idle1));

Comment: This gives me the result 0

Answer (score 0):

```
float x = 100.5;
float result = x - (int)x;
if (result != 0)
{
    //If the value of `result` is not equal to zero, then, you have a decimal portion which is not equal to 0.

//If you want integer result
Integer yourAnswer1 = (Integer)result;

Float yourAnswer2 = (float)result;

}
```

Comment: float x = 100.5; it says: Required float, found double.

Comment: sorry, just replace float x = 100.5; with float x = 100.5f;

Answer (score 0):

```
float f=2443.4333;
println(Math.floor(f)+"");
```

this will give you result 2443.0

Comment: Thanks Raut, but i want to remove completely the decimals.

Comment: float will always have the decimal, better change it to integer

Comment: ok then, how can i do this? because when i change it to integer, the result is always 0

Comment: float flt=20.234234234234;
println(((int)Math.floor(flt))+""); It gives result 20